# Combining Opencv Raw frames with Microphone Audio stream Using ffmpeg

Tags: python, opencv, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to build a sports analysis platform where I have a deep learning model which processes Live video(RTMP/Webcam) frames, applies overlays,score etc. and then I need to combine it with microphone audio and rebroadcast with audio and video in sync. I think I need the presentation time stamps of the frames (Since AI frame processing takes variable time) and somehow provide ffmpeg with it but I'm lost and could not find a similar example doing this.

Comment: So, what is your actual question? Can you provide any code we can replicate?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.